# Why the Emulator does not get FCM Push

Tags: android, android-emulator

Log shows successful results
Works well on other devices but does not accept Emulator What's wrong?

```
{"multicast_id":8493162742008674298,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1553044762094963%04b2fb58f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow this instruction.I hope you will get solution.

```
 1. Uninstall your apps form emulator.
 2. Again Install or run apps in emulator.
 3. Get new FCM id and use it.
```